# How to update textview value based on progressbar progress in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, objectanimator

I would like to use `ObjectAnimator` to animate by `ProgressBar` progress. However, I wouldn't be able to update the text since I am not using a for loop. What is the best way to update the `Textview` while using `ObjectAnimator`? Here is what I've tried to update it but I failed to do so:

```
val animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressbar, "progress", 0, 10000)
   animation.setDuration(2000)
   animation.setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
   animation.start()
   var progress=progressbar.getProgress() /100
   progtxt.text="$progress%"
```

Comment: what you use for `progressbar` ?

Comment: I mean `SeekBar` or `ProgressBar`

Comment: @DineshShingadiya its for telling the user the progress like load menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ObjectAnimator` you can use an update listener:

```
    animation.addUpdateListener(object: ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
        override fun onAnimationUpdate(animation: ValueAnimator?) {
            val progress = animation?.animatedValue as Int
            // Update you text view
        }
    })
```

Here in `onAnimationUpdate` you can get animated value or progress bar progress depending on what you need and set it to your text view.

Comment: @TechMaxed, `TextView.setText(int)` method accepts string resource id (like `R.string.text`). To set number as a text use `TextView.text = progress.toString()`

Comment: or TextView.text = "$progress"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can be able to do this with the animation.

But you can use the [SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out but what I am using is a progressbar not a seekbar